# placing the media uploads in a subdirectory

Tags: permalinks, cdn

Hi I want all my uploads to be uploaded to a subdomain on my site instead of 'wp-content/uploads'

I created a subdomain `cdn.mysite.com` and i want all the uploads to go there instead.

I want my uploads to be `cdn.mysite.com/uploads/year/month/mediafile`

Just as the uploads automatically create a folder for the uploads i want it to do the same when uploading to the subdomain.

How can I accomplish this.

EDIT:

I found this plugin that is suppose to place the image path options back on wordpress but I'm not so sure i should use it, I don't know if it actually works, I don't want to mess anything up

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-original-media-path/installation/

Also I found this tutorial of how to do this from the wp-config.php file but it's only explaining changing the name of the folder not changing the path as in placing a subdomain.

http://www.techgyd.com/how-to-change-media-uploads-folder-in-wordpress-3-5/17/

I want to try the second option, editing the wp-config.php file but I don't know how to edit that line of code for subdomains, also I'm afraid that if we do figure out how to add the subdomain option to the wp-config file that when I upgrade wordpress it will disappear and my images may mess up.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your theme's functions.php file, making sure you replace the example CDN URL with your own:

```
function my_cdn_upload_url() {
    return 'http://mk124.yourcdn.com/yoursite/wp-content/uploads';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', 'my_cdn_upload_url' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the sites hosted in such a way that you could create symbolic link within your primary site's directory structure to the physical storage location of cdn.mysite.com? You'd be linking `wp-content/uploads -> /path/to/storage/for/cdn.mysite.com/uploads` .

You'd likely need both sites' hosting running under the same user, but if they're co-located, this might be as simple as a symlink.

Comment: yes they are hosted under the same user........ the way it's set up is that the root of `mysite.com` has a folder called `files` and the subdirectory `cdn.mysite.com` will point to that folder or is there another way to set this up

Comment: i just realized that by creating a subdomain on the site and the subdomain files actually linking to the folder on the site won't make the site go any faster and that was my intentions :(

Comment: Actually, it will. Most browsers have a limit to the number of connections they can make to a single domain at a given time. By putting some of your content in a subdomain, you increase that limit by at least a factor of 2.

Comment: So, to answer your other question. If your directory layout looks something like this:

site
site/wp-content
site/files
site/files/cdn.mysite.com

and you have shell access to it, you can create a symbolic link from within site/wp-content. The command would look something like:

`mkdir -p site/files/cdn.mysite.com/uploads`
`ln -s site/files/cdn.mysite.com/uploads site/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: Matt, no need to use symlinks, it is possible to set [two WP settings for that](http://www.techtipsgeek.com/host-images-wordpress-blog-subdomain-better-speed/6897/). Nowadays, they are in `/wp-admin/options.php`.

Comment: Ah, good point. You can set the path to the uploads directory. Sorry, I forgot about that.

Comment: You can [edit]/update your Answer whenever you want/need ;) ::::: Oh, yes, use `@username` so the other party receives a notification. The Question/Answer owner always receive one, there are nuances but that's pretty much it, check the [faq].

Comment: Problem.....In my media settings there is no option to change path of the media storage @brasofilo

Comment: @MattShelton Check my edit

Comment: @brasofilo Check My Edit